# System.out.println output to JTextArea

Tags: java, console, jtextarea

I would like to everytime I call System.out.println to append to a given JTextArea, without having to change all calls to System.out.println... Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Versions of Java since 1.5 have `System.setOut()` which allow you to install your own `PrintStream`. Just create a simple `OutputStream` which appends the data it get through `write()` Then wrap it in a `PrintStream` and install it.

Answer (score 1):

Well You can do it using the `jTextArea.append("Your String")` method

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a simple way. I generally try to avoid `System.out` calls in my code for exactly this sort of reason. If you have a method like (say) `MyUtil.myOutput()` then you can make a single change and reroute it where you want

Comment: yeah, it's more for dealing with some legacy stuff I have here.. sure if I would make it from stratch I would use log4j

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you could potentially use some form of [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) to do it, but I think that may be overkill.  What I would do though is create a method that would both print and append.

```
public void printAndAppend(String text) {
      System.out.println(text);
      textArea.append(text);
}
```

You can then just do a global find and replace for `System.out.println` and replace it with `printAndAppend`